# vim script replace until match

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I am trying to match a block of fortran, say,

```
foo i()
...
End foo i
```

with

```
autocmd CursorMovedI *.f90  :call FixName("foo")
```

where `FixName` is:

```
" FixName: Change Subprogram name {{{1
function! FixName(arg)
    let [buf, l, c, off] = getpos('.')
    call cursor([1, 1, 0])

    let lnum = search('\v\c^\s*' . a:arg . '\s+', 'cnW')
    if !lnum
        call cursor(l, c, off)
        return
    endif

    let parts = matchlist(getline(lnum), '\v\c^\s*' . a:arg . '\s+(\S*)\s*$')
    if len(parts) < 2
        call cursor(l, c, off)
        return
    endif

    let lnum = search('\v\c^\s*End\s*' . a:arg . '\s+', 'cnW')
    call cursor(l, c, off)
    if !lnum
        return
    endif

    call setline(lnum, substitute(getline(lnum), '\v\c^\s*End\s*' . a:arg . '\s+\zs.*', parts[1], ''))
endfunction
```

The problem is, with this FixName, I am getting anything after the foo. So, if I have, `foo bar(anything)`, I am ending up with `End foo bar(anything)`. But, I want only the bar (i.e. before the "**(**").

I have tried to change the last line as:

```
 call setline(lnum, substitute(getline(lnum), '\v\c^\s*End\s*' . a:arg . '\s+\zs.*[?=\(]', parts[1], ''))
```

but obviously that's not the correct way.
How should I correct it?

Comment: Should parts end with `'\s+(\S*)\(.*\)\s*$'`?

Comment: yes, but I need to terminate it before "(". Say, in python, I would do something like `\s+(.*)(?=\()`. But, vim is complaining about `E866: misplaced ?`

Comment: I meant you could use the string I provided instead of the one you currently use: `let parts = matchlist(getline(lnum), '\v\c^\s*' . a:arg . '\s+(\S*)\(.*\)\s*$')`. As for what your Python code does: [`:h zero-width`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fzero-width).

Comment: Ah, ok...thanks. I misunderstood your comment. Yes...that is working (but no idea how and why :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `'\s+(\S*)\s*$'` in matching for `parts`, you could use `'\s+(\S*)\(.*\)\s*$'`. `()` in a magic regex (`\v`) is, of course, used for grouping, so to match for literal parentheses, you need to use `\(\)`. `'\s+(\S*)\(.*\)\s*$'` thus matches whitespace, followed by non-whitespace, then a pair of parentheses containing anything. So, the grouped part only matches the text before the opening parenthesis.

Comment: Hi, sorry, as this solves the problem what I have asked for. But, I realize, that I need to make the `()` things optional. Is it possible to make the \( optional? i.e. it should match the characters until the end of line or the (?

Comment: Like this? `'\s+(\S*)\(.*\)?\s*$'`

Comment: sorry but it is not changing any behavior. what I am looking for is matching `foo` either for `foo` or `foo(bar)`

Comment: Ah, the entire `(bar)` is optional. Then: `'\s+(\S*)(\(.*\))?\s*$'`

Comment: oh no...then you have bought the (bar) back. I don't want the `(bar)`. only `foo` for both `foo` and `foo(bar)`

Comment: Hmm. That regex was greedy, so when `\(.*\)` became optional, `\S*` matched it as well. Maybe `'\s+(\S{-})(\(.*\))?\s*$'`, but not sure